# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https:// 2020 node js

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server, cloud9-ide

There are so many questions asked based on this issue but none solves my problem.
I am using cloud9 IDE for my development. I am trying to receive data from node server to angular project using a API. My node.js server has all the CORS header required. But I continue to receive the error.
Here is my server code:

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = 8080,
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());  


const { expressCspHeader, INLINE, NONE, SELF } = require('express-csp-header');
 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
 
app.use(expressCspHeader({
    policies: {
        'default-src': [expressCspHeader.NONE],
        'img-src': [expressCspHeader.SELF],
    }
})); 
    
app.use(cors());   
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    else {
      next();
    }});



var routes = require('./api/routes/doRoutes'); //importing route
routes(app);
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.status(404).send({url: req.originalUrl + ' not found'});
});
app.listen(port);

console.log('RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

Here is the error on firefox browser:

[image]

Is it the IDE thats causing the problem? Or am i missing out on something? Please help !

Comment: Alright ! I guess i found the issue. The problem was with the IDE, i ran the server from localhost and everything started working. Though I'd wanna know why does it happen with cloud9

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you only have the get verb enabled in your backend

Change this:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
```

for this:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
```

Comment: Thankyou for commenting. I tried that, it gives the same error.

Comment: ok then add the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the request en the front end

Comment: the request header is not working, it has given error as "req.header is not a function"